# on facebook, how do i authenticate an application, using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, authentication, curl

I can only find samples using php or curl.

I want to do something like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<app_id>/accounts/test-users?
                                installed=true&permissions=read_stream
```

as documented here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#client_credentials

and the response is:

```
{
    "error": {
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "message": "An access token is required to request this resource."
    }
}
```

as well is should...  so how do i get the access token in JavaScript (using the JavaScript SDK obviously).

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was a testament to my need to learn more and more... ended up installing curl (from http://curl.haxx.se) and using http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html to modify the examples at developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#client_credentials.

Answer (score 0):

After the user has connected through the JavaScript SDK, you will have the access token.

You don't really need to know them on the client side, because you can just use `FB.api` to do Graph API and REST API calls.

See also: Facebook Authentication Guide, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/, particularly the Single Sign-on with the JavaScript SDK part.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not looking to authenticate a user, but an application. See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#client_credentials